# Eclipse doesn't show the package in the explorer

Tags: eclipse, src

Usually it showed in my src file, but now it seems to be replaced by folders.

When I try to make a package (com.levdl.tutorial), it gets split up in folder like this:

http://prntscr.com/2u604p

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Hi Dennis, i just wanted to tell you that the [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/) IDE is better supported at HRO Rotterdam ;)

Comment: Haha yea I noticed! I am using IntelliJ right now. Are you a student at HRO as well?

Comment: Yes i am, i got notified about the post by Dominic Hasselt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the view to either `"project explorer"` or java `"package explorer".`

goto `windows> show view> genereal > project explorer`

or

goto `windows> show view> java> package explorer`

you navigator view will show your packages like folder views

Comment: Man thanks alot. ive been stuck on this for half a day. Thanks for helping out a rookie!

Answer (score 1):

Your src/ folder is not in the Build path:

Right-click on your src/ folder -> Build Path -> Use as Source Folder

Clean your project afterwards: Project -> Clean